# CodeReview: CycleGAN Implementation Using Keras FunctionalAPI

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, ai

Okay So I Am Here Implementing the cyclegan architecture with using keras api
from scratch.

For Those who Wanna Know More About Cyclegan [seehere](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.10593)

The CycleGan Compose of Two Phase Architecture Like Any Other GAN
Here Is My Implementation Of Both Architecture You Have Just Have To Confirm Both Architecure In Correct Form/Order

**1.Discriminator(PatchGAN)**
[image: patchgan]

```
# Discriminator
model_input=(217,217,1)

input_layer=keras.Input(shape=model_input)

k2_layer=ly.Conv2D(64,(4,4),(2,2),padding='valid')(input_layer)
norm=tfa.layers.InstanceNormalization()(k2_layer)
activation=ly.LeakyReLU(0.2)(norm)


k4_layer=ly.Conv2D(128,(4,4),(2,2),padding='valid')(activation)
norm=tfa.layers.InstanceNormalization()(k4_layer)
activation=ly.LeakyReLU(0.2)(norm)

k8_layer=ly.Conv2D(256,(4,4),(2,2),padding='valid')(activation)
norm=tfa.layers.InstanceNormalization()(k8_layer)
activation=ly.LeakyReLU(0.2)(norm)

k16layer=ly.Conv2D(512,(4,4),(2,2),padding='valid')(activation)
norm=tfa.layers.InstanceNormalization()(k16layer)
activation=ly.LeakyReLU(0.2)(norm)

patchgan=ly.Conv2D(1,(4,4),(1,1),padding='valid',activation='sigmoid')(activation)


Discriminator=keras.Model(input_layer,patchgan,name='Discriminator')

Discriminator.summary()
```

[image: discriminator-summary]

**2.Generator**
[image: generator-architecture]

```
#model

#genrator

from keras import layers as ly


input_layer=keras.Input(model_input)
#Downsampling
k_layer=ly.Conv2D(64,(7,7),(1,1),padding='valid')(input_layer)
k2_layer=ly.Conv2D(128,(3,3),(2,2),padding='valid')(k_layer)
k4_layer=ly.Conv2D(256,(3,3),(2,2),padding='valid')(k2_layer)

#Tunneling
k4_layer1=ly.Conv2D(256,(3,3),(1,1),padding='same')(k4_layer)
skip_conn=ly.Add()([k4_layer,k4_layer1])
k4_layer2=ly.Conv2D(256,(3,3),(1,1),padding='same')(skip_conn)
skip_conn=ly.Add()([k4_layer1,k4_layer2])
k4_layer3=ly.Conv2D(256,(3,3),(1,1),padding='same')(skip_conn)
skip_conn=ly.Add()([k4_layer2,k4_layer3])
k4_layer4=ly.Conv2D(256,(3,3),(1,1),padding='same')(skip_conn)
skip_conn=ly.Add()([k4_layer3,k4_layer4])
k4_layer5=ly.Conv2D(256,(3,3),(1,1),padding='same')(skip_conn)
skip_conn=ly.Add()([k4_layer4,k4_layer5])
k4_layer6=ly.Conv2D(256,(3,3),(1,1),padding='same')(skip_conn)
skip_conn=ly.Add()([k4_layer5,k4_layer6])

# Upsampling
k2_layer=ly.Conv2DTranspose(128,(3,3),(2,2),padding='valid')(skip_conn)
k_layer=ly.Conv2DTranspose(64,(3,3),(2,2),padding='valid')(k2_layer)
k_layer=ly.Conv2D(3,(7,7),(1,1),padding='valid')(k_layer)

genrator=keras.Model(input_layer,k_layer,name='Genrator')
genrator.summary()
```

[image: generator-summary]